# Gratis profiler for C and OpenMP (parallelization, multithreading)

Tags: gratis, c, performance-analysis

I am writing programs in C language which uses OpenMP for multi-threading and code parallelization in Windows 10 / Linux (using Intel processor).

I need to profile them visually, I mean, I need graphics about each thread, its execution time, difference between the linear code and the parallelized code, etc.

Something like:

[image]

This picture has been taken using [Score-P](https://www.vi-hps.org/projects/score-p/) (for recording) + [Vampir](https://vampir.eu/) (for visualization). But I can not afford to buy Vampir, so I need a free-alternative.

Anyone knows which application could I use for achieving that?

Comment: Look at tools listed at https://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-compilers-tools/ . Hpctoolkit caught my eye, but I've not tried it. Students may be eligible for intel vtune licenses.

Comment: @OldBadmanGrey Ok! I will take a look. Thank you.

Comment: @OldBadmanGrey exist any tutorial for Windows10 + OpenMP + VTune? I have been researching and I only found tutorials for Linux